# Configuring CakePHP with XAMPP

Tags: cakephp

I have been using CakePHP at work and now I am trying to set it up at home. I have a projects folder inside of htdocs and within that folder I have my cakeProject .../htdocs/Projects/CakeProject/app.... When I point the url to localhost/Projects/cakeProject/ I get this error.

Missing Controller

Error: ProjectsController could not be found....

And it goes on explaining how to make a controller. Clearly, this is not the real issue. Can anyone see right away what am I overlooking??

Here is the Stack Trace:
Stack Trace

```
APP\webroot\index.php line 92 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');



$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

$Dispatcher->dispatch(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse(array('charset' => Configure::read('App.encoding'))));

object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        [maximum depth reached]
    )
    data => array([maximum depth reached])
    query => array([maximum depth reached])
    url => 'projects/cakeProject/'
    base => '/projects/cakeProject/app/webroot/index.php'
    webroot => '/projects/cakeProject/app/webroot/'
    here => '/projects/cakeProject/app/webroot/index.php/projects/cakeProject/'
}
object(CakeResponse) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem was. I must have set something up wrong during installation. I deleted the Project from the Projects folder. Recloned it and it is working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your webroot folder?
You have to configure the webroot before doing anything.

I don't know which operating system are you using, but the third result on google for this topic is a detailed [guide](http://mushfiqrazib.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/configure-cakephp-with-xampp/) with xamp in windows.
Maybe it can help you

Comment: I am in Windows. I have followed a similar guide to setting things up. I am not exactly sure what you mean by configuring my webroot, which by the way is in htdocs/Projects/cakeProject/app. I configured core.php, database.php, and routes.php